# I am unable to update my SQL database in Python, but can add new rows

Tags: python, sql, mysql-connector, google-hangouts

I apologise if similar has been posted before (it no doubt has) but I can't seem to find a question that has a similar issue. I am building a basic ticketing system bot using Python, SQL and Hangouts Chat. The Chat part isn't really relevant. At a core level, all I am trying to do is update a very basic SQL database with a Python Script. I can insert and view my records fine. Please note that I am also using this in a hangouts chat bot, so I apologise for that, as well as the fact my code is very 'wide open' at the moment, as I am debugging it by looking at each variable separately. I will neaten it all up when I am done.

```
        elif "!update" in messagesentstr:
            messagesentstrsplit = messagesentstr.split(" ", 3) #Takes string from Hangouts Chat message and splits it in to 4
            messagesentstrsplitid = messagesentstrsplit[2] #Takes the row number to be updated from the chat message
            myint = int(messagesentstrsplitid) #Converts the number to an int from string
            mycursor.execute("SELECT issue FROM tickets WHERE id = %d" % (myint)) #Pulls the relevant record

            myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
            outputwithchar = json.dumps(myresult)
            outputnochar = outputwithchar[2:-2]
            updatedcol = outputnochar + ' ' + messagesentstrsplit[3]
            mytuple = (updatedcol,)
            sqlupdatecom = "UPDATE tickets SET issue = (%s) WHERE id = (%d)"
            mycursor.execute(sqlupdatecom, mytuple, myint)
            mydb.commit()
            print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")

            updatedcolmsg = 'The ticket with the ID ' + str(myint) + ' has been updated to: "' + updatedcol + '"'
            texttoshow = (updatedcolmsg)
```

In an example, messagesentstr would equal '!update 12 I then did this.'. Row 12 would already have 'I have this issue.' under the issue column.

When run, I get '-1 record(s) affected' but no errors, and my record stays the same. I would expect to get 'I have this issue. I then did this.' for issue id 12.

Thanks

EDIT: Have noticed it works fine when I put a value in, instead of %s, so my string is probably not actually a string

Comment: When you did a string format in you UPDATE statement you are formatting a tuple value, change it to base string are see if it is working or not.

Comment: @NishantPatelHave done, still no luck. Replaced the tuple with a basic string and still -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with a similar issue, changing to:

```
sqlupdatecom = (
                "UPDATE tickets SET issue = %s "
                "WHERE id = %s")
                mycursor.execute(sqlupdatecom, (updatedcol, myint))
                mydb.commit()
```

fixed it for me